# Parsing SOAP response : empty object

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm trying to parse a SOAP response from a server (Chronopost WebServices) but I really don't know what I am messing up. The question has been asked many times but I can't find any answer that works.

[Here is the SOAP response](https://ws.chronopost.fr/recherchebt-ws-cxf/PointRelaisServiceWS/rechercheBtParCodeproduitEtCodepostalEtDate?codePostal=28500&date=27/09/2016)

The response looks like below :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<ns1:rechercheBtParCodeproduitEtCodepostalEtDateResponse xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.rechercheBt.soap.chronopost.fr/">
<return>
<adresse1>42 RUE SAINT DENIS</adresse1>
<codePostal>28100</codePostal>
<dateArriveColis>2016-09-25T10:46:30.778+02:00</dateArriveColis>
<horairesOuvertureDimanche>08:00-13:00 00:00-00:00</horairesOuvertureDimanche>
<horairesOuvertureJeudi>07:15-12:00 12:00-20:00</horairesOuvertureJeudi>
<horairesOuvertureLundi>07:15-12:00 12:00-20:00</horairesOuvertureLundi>
<horairesOuvertureMardi>07:15-12:00 12:00-20:00</horairesOuvertureMardi>
<horairesOuvertureMercredi>00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00</horairesOuvertureMercredi>
<horairesOuvertureSamedi>08:00-12:00 12:00-20:00</horairesOuvertureSamedi>
<horairesOuvertureVendredi>07:15-12:00 12:00-20:00</horairesOuvertureVendredi>
<identifiantChronopostPointA2PAS>2924P</identifiantChronopostPointA2PAS>
<localite>DREUX</localite>
<nomEnseigne>LE LONGCHAMP</nomEnseigne>
<coordGeoLatitude>48.7344444</coordGeoLatitude>
<coordGeoLongitude>1.37138888</coordGeoLongitude>
<urlGoogleMaps>http://maps.google.fr/maps?q=48.7344444,1.37138888</urlGoogleMaps>
</return>
```

I've tried to parse this file in PHP with :

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://ws.chronopost.fr/recherchebt-ws-cxf/PointRelaisServiceWS/rechercheBtParCodeproduitEtCodepostalEtDate?codePostal=28500&date=27/09/2016');
$clean_xml = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', $response);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml);
var_dump($xml);
```

Which returns me an empty object and I don't get why :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#287 (1) {
  ["Body"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#280 (0) {
  }
}
```

**Edit :** some more informations : working with Laravel 5.2 and its server (`php artisan serve`). No errors reported in the console log.

Comment: That's not an empty object, it's the object for the "Body" element of the XML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and why do I only get the Body element and not the others ?

Comment: It sort of has a 'cursor' which defaults to the first element.  It doesn't recursively show all the child elements.  If you want to inspect the Body element you would access it directly like: var_dump($xml->Body).  But I have another question: can you not use PHP's built-in soapclient?  Then you wont have to worry about parsing XML.

Comment: Ok now I get it, thanks ! Well I'd still need to parse data in my PHP back-end, what else but soapclient would you recommand ?